# The WS-AtomicTransaction protocol service could not unmarshal the flowed transaction.

Tags: wcf

The flowed transaction could not be unmarshaled. The following exception occurred: The WS-AtomicTransaction protocol service could not unmarshal the flowed transaction. The following exception occured: A fault reply with code CoordinatorRegistrationFailed was received. The fault reason follows: The WS-AT protocol service failed to register with its coordinator. A connection could not be established.

I am using WCF Service

When I use Transacton in nettcpbinding over internet
it Work Completly on the LAN network

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. You may try this.

Open component services in server machine and expand component services and then expand computers expand my computer and expand distributed transaction coordinator right click local DTC open properties: Go to Security tab, enable Network DTC Access and then enable Allow Inbound in Transaction manager communication leave other settings.

Now open Component Services in Client machine follow above and go to local DTC properties open security tab , enable Network DTC Access and then enable Allow Outbound in Transaction manager communication leave other settings.